# java regex expression escape characters

Tags: java, regex

Hi i'm trying to split a string separated by vertical bars. for example:

```
String str = "a=1|b=2";
```

In java, we should do like this:

```
 str.split("\\|");
```

If I use a single slash:

```
str.split("\|");
```

compiler gives errors:

> Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )

Can anyone explain me why this happens? thanks!

Comment: The `|` symbol has special meaning in a regex, so it needs to be escaped.  Because the backslash character _also_ has special meaning in strings (it is an escape character) it needs to be escaped there as well.  So... you need two `\ ` symbols in your regex.  This has been covered many many times on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backslash `\` is a special character. In the Java world it is used to escape a character.

The pipe `|` is a special character in the Regex world, which means "*OR*".

To use the pipe as a separator you need to escape it(so it can be recognized during the regex parsing), so you need to get this in your regex: `\|`.

But as backshlash is a special character in Java and that you are using a String object, you have to escape the backslash so it can be interpreted as the final expected final result: `\|`

To do so, you simply escape backslash with another backslash: `\\|`

The first backslash escapes the second backslash (java requirement) which escapes the pipe (regex requirement).

Answer (score 1):

In Java strings, a backslash needs to be escaped with another backslash. So, while the "canonical" form of the regex is indeed `\|`, as a Java string, this must be written `"\\|"`.